# how can i optimize this pseudo code

Tags: python, matrix, optimization, networkx

i am new user in python... i know that question very primitive but my project have lots of sets and i need effective and fast code

i want to generate a matrix with if condition. 
for example:
          M=Matrix(m[i,j] if Condition1 and Condition2 and ...)

how can i optimize following pseudo code?

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
#G=nx.graph()
#G.neighbors(node)
def seidel_matrix(G):
    n=nx.number_of_nodes(G)
    x=np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i==j:
                x[i][j]=0
            elif i in G.neighbors(j):
                x[i][j]=-1
            else:
                x[i][j]=1
    return x
```

Comment: please add code with sufficient information what is G in your case? what does G.neighbors do? and many more.. also please write what you want to do/expecting to be done with code

Comment: Your desired output is 0 on the diagonal of the matrix, +1 if there is no edge and -1 if there is?  Is that correct?

Comment: i am so sorry Gahan  i just edit my question. yes my desire look like

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple ways to do this.  Right now, you're looping over every possible edge.  If there are lots of non-edges this is a poor choice.  It would be faster to just loop over every edge that actually exists.

```
x = np.ones((n,n))  #default entry is 1.
for u, v in G.edges():   #get edges right
    x[u][v] = -1
    x[v][u] = -1 #assuming undirected network
for u in G.nodes():  #get diagonal right.
    x[u][u] = 0
```

Note that this assumes that the nodes are labeled `0`, `1`, ..., `n-1`